# bulk compare in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a csv file with one column. Each row in this column may have a match record in TestTable from database (sample table only). I would like to send the entire data via C# to the stored procedure one time and return the rows from the database if it has a match.

**Input parameter (csv column):**
**Stringcolumn**
apple
banana
copper
dig
....

**Output (possibly dataset):**
ID|StringColumn|AddedDate
2|apple|2021-01-02
35|copper|2021-01-02

The requirement is to send and receive the data via C#.

Right now, I'm thinking to use User-Defined Table Types in MS SQL to receive the data.

Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way would be using the `IN` clause, but if there were too many parameters a user defined data type like the one you are thinking about would be better from a performance point.

Comment: You do not ask a question. You seem to have identified an approach, so what is stopping you from acting on that?

Comment: I'm just asking if there's another way. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a big csv I would recommend dumping it in a temp table and then using a join to get the data. Alternatively you can use user defined table type to pass the data into a stored procedure

Comment: I already tried the user defined table type and it works fine. I'm just looking for another alternative if ever. Thanks anyway.